# Python IndexError Out of Range

Tags: python

This is my program

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
fn=sys.argv[1]
dt=open(fn).readlines()
  for ln in dt:
    fd=ln.split()
    cntw=fd[1].count("W")
    print cntw
```

It reads the file completely but at the end gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./task0.py", line 7, in <module>
    cntw=fd[1].count("W")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why is this and what do I need to change?

Comment: if you show us the content of file, will be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line is empty, skip it:

```
for ln in dt:
    fd = ln.split()
    if not fd:
        continue
```

An empty line results in an empty list:

```
>>> ''.split()
[]
```

and the `not fd` test is true for empty containers.

Note that you don't have to read all lines into memory first; drop the `readlines()` call and loop over the open file object directly; use a `with` statement to have Python auto-close it for you when done:

```
with open(fn) as fileobj:
    for ln in fileobj:
        fd = ln.split()
        if not fd:
            continue
        cntw = fd[1].count("W")
        print cntw
```

Comment: what is a line only has one element? `if len(fd ) < 2` would make sure there are at least two elements

Comment: ^ what Padraic said.  It is much better to use exception handling.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Perhaps the OP *wants* to get an exception when there is no second element on a line? Empty lines are usually fine.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the file would help to understand what you are trying to accomplish, but here is a more Pythonic solution.  You should use a try and except statement to catch the exception and use the with keyword (as Martijn Pieters suggested) to auto-close the file when done.

Also, this isn't the 1990s... I'd suggest using variable names that give an idea of their purpose.  I don't know what you are trying to do, but I made some changes to try and get the point across :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
filename = sys.argv[1]

with open(filename) as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
        words = line.split()

        try:
            wcount = words[1].count("W")
        except IndexError:
            continue
```